# in expressions, `_` can only be used on the left-hand side of an assignment

Tags: rust, casting

I've the following code I implemented to return an error when a string doesn't contain a match to something like "Mark, 55" to return an error. The compiler complains about my code `Err(error) =>  Err(ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_))`

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: usize,
}

// We will use this error type for the `FromStr` implementation.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum ParsePersonError {
    // Empty input string
    Empty,
    // Incorrect number of fields
    BadLen,
    // Empty name field
    NoName,
    // Wrapped error from parse::<usize>()
    ParseInt(ParseIntError),
}
// My implementation 
    impl FromStr for Person {
        type Err = ParsePersonError;
        fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Person, Self::Err> {

    if s.len() == 0 {
        Err(ParsePersonError::Empty)    
    }
    else {
        let v: Vec<&str> = s.split(",").collect();
        println!("{:?}",v);
        if &v[0]== &""{
            Err(ParsePersonError::NoName)
        } 
        else if v.len()!=2 {
            Err(ParsePersonError::BadLen)
        }
        else {
            let num = match v[1].parse::<usize>() {
                Ok(n) => {
                    
                    let name = v[0].to_string();
                    let age = n;
                    return Ok(Person {name,age})
                },

                Err(error) =>  Err(ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_))
            }; 

            Err(ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_))
            
        }
            
    }
}
```

}

However, the compiler doesn't complain about the same code in my test case.

```
ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_))

     #[test]
        fn missing_name_and_age() {
            assert!(matches!(
                ",".parse::<Person>(),
                Err(ParsePersonError::NoName | ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_))
            ));
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: _ means any int. You can use it on the left hand side of a match. Try using cargo expand and look at the code the matches macro generates.

Comment: Your `Err(ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_))` is outside the `match`.

Answer (score 1):

If you de-sugar the match macro in test, it is something like

```
let result = ",".parse::<Person>();
let r = match result {
    Err(ParsePersonError::NoName) => true,
    Err(ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_)) => true,
    _ => false,
};
assert!(r);
```

Essentially the `'_'` is to hold the value attached to `ParseInt`. Hence an assignment. This is what the compiler error message means.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same error. Instead of

```
Err(error) =>  Err(ParsePersonError::ParseInt(_))
```

just pass down the value held by Err to the enum variant:

```
Err(error) =>  Err(ParsePersonError::ParseInt(error))
```

The last Err is outside the match, so it's better to refactor that flow first.